# End outgoing call using Twilio programmable voice sdk

Tags: ios, swift, twilio

I am using Twilio new voice SDK for iOS i.e Twilio programmable voice SDK I have successfully implemented for making outgoing call but not able to end call. In the Twilio SDK there is method of disconnect()

so i have implemented

```
var outgoingCall:TVOOutgoingCall?
outgoingCall?.disconnect()
```

For ending a call it is not giving any error but not ending call, Please give any suggestion.

Comment: That's the correct method, so I'm not sure what's going on. Is there anything logged or an error thrown at all? Do you definitely have an instance of `outgoingCall` when you are calling `disconnect` on it?

Comment: when i implementing a call on my side I'm getting voice message application error has occurred and on the other side voice message saying  you successfully make your first call press key to continue and call drops automatically.

Comment: I was having the similar problem.
I had showed the calling view only after successful connection (by checking in delegate) .

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
if (self.call != nil && self.call?.state == .connected) {
        self.call?.disconnect()
    }
```

Check if call object is not null and call state.